# Is there a way to have the client side script also auto loaded from the proxy/cluster services in the Ara Framework?

Tags: hypernova

First of all a great framework for SSR based MFEs . I was trying out the Ara / Svelte (Micro App1) / Vue (Micro App 2) / Nuxt JS (Appshell) as described in https://ara-framework.github.io/website/blog/2019/08/27/nuxt-js as well as setup the cluster and proxy as described in the docs https://ara-framework.github.io/website/docs/nova-cluster

In the App shell in the Nuxt App I need to include the client side scripts like this

```
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: 'http://localhost:3000/public/client.js' },
      { src: 'http://localhost:3001/public/client.js' }
    ]
  }
```

Is there a better way to discover and load this scripts , similar to the server side part is handled by the proxy and the cluster servers ? The problem with the current approach is I need to know where the nova server client scripts are deployed before hand.

Comment: Ok I looked at your new samples on ara https://github.com/marconi1992/ara-spa-vue/blob/master/spa/src/main.js and I guess we can use the views.json and `loadscript` helper to externalize the client scripts and load them on the `NovaMount` event.

Comment: I was able to use the same logic in a `nuxtjs` sample and use sort of externalized client scripts similar to the sample above and it works https://github.com/tsukhu/ara-sample/commit/b310fbfd6a7af71718b8af7b66f00dc5c706aba9 . However the question is can this be done or accessed from the same cluster server so that we don't need to add this information in two places ?

Answer (score 0):

As you describe in the comments, using the `NovaMount` event is the best approach so far. Unfortunately, there's nothing out of the box to do it without explicitly define the bundle URLs yet.

However, we plan to add a new feature to [Nova Proxy](https://github.com/ara-framework/nova-proxy) to make that easier.

In the `getComponent` helper, we can use the `returnMeta` property from the second parameter to return the client script URL in the Hypernova response.

```js
hypernova({
  getComponent (name, { returnMeta }) {
    returnMeta.src = 'http://localhost:3000/public/client.js'
  }
})
```

We get something like this in the Hypernova response.

```
{
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "results": {
        "example": {
            "name": "Example",
            "HTML": "...",
            "meta": {
                "src": "http://localhost:3000/public/client.js"
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

We plan to inject that client URL in Nova Proxy when including the Nova views as well.

I created this Github issue where you can follow-up on the feature progress.
https://github.com/ara-framework/nova-proxy/issues/10